# Using python string formatting in a django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is there an easy way to use python string formatting from within a django template?  That is, I'd like to be able to do something like this in a template

```
{{ variable|%.3f }}
```

I know in this case, one can just use

```
{{ variable|floatformat:3 }}
```

But I'd really like to be able to generically use any python string format on a django variable.  In my system it's inconvenient to have to deal with two different ways to format output (python vs django), so I'd like to standardize.  I could write a custom template tag like

```
{% pyformat variable format="%.3f" %}
```

or maybe a custom template filter like

```
{{ variable|pyformat:"%.3f" }}
```

Do either of these already exist?  Will the customer filter work with a string passed in like that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
{{ variable|stringformat:".3f" }}
```

*Source: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat*

Comment: "This specifier uses Python string formatting syntax, with the exception that the leading "%" is dropped"

Comment: Note lack of space between `stringformat` and `".3f"` is important! If there is space, then it will crash with "stringformat required 2 arguments, 1 provided" exception!

Answer (score 3):

[`stringformat`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat)

Answer (score 0):

I had omit the "%":

```
    {{ variable|stringformat:".3f" }}
```